# Процедуры в PascalABC.NET

Tags: winforms, pascalabc.net, textbox, procedure

столкнулся со следующей проблемой: в Форме рисуется график с определенными параметрами, в этой же форме присутствует текст-бокс с помощью которого можно изменять параметры. Как сделать так, чтобы после обновления параметра, без перезапуска программы, процедура выполнялась заново и рисовала новый график, уже учитывая измененный параметр. Пытался повторно вызвать процедуру в процедуре текст бокса, но не получилось. Повторный запуск формы внутри процедуры, выдает ошибку. Как можно реализовать то, что изначально задумывалось?

```
Program BetterKursach;

{$reference System.Windows.Forms.dll}
{$reference System.Drawing.dll}
{$apptype windows}
{$Val.PAS}
uses System.Windows.Forms;
uses System.Drawing;
uses System;
uses System.Net;

Label m;

function cot(x:real):real;
  begin
  cot:=cos(x)/sin(x);
  end;

function F1(x:real):real;
  begin
  F1 := tan(x);
  end;

var   

      Txt: TextBox;
      Form1: System.Windows.Forms.Form; 
      G1: System.Drawing.Graphics;
      i, b, x0, y0, xx, yy, code:integer;
      x, mx, my:real;
      i1, i2, o:string;
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

procedure osi (sender : object; e : System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs); //Построение осей
begin

         G1.DrawLine (new System.Drawing.Pen (System.Drawing.Color.Black,1), 0,y0,500,y0); //Ось икс
         G1.DrawLine (new System.Drawing.Pen (System.Drawing.Color.Black,1), x0,0,x0,500); //Ось игрек

         for var i:=1 to b do
           begin
              str(i,i1);
              str(-i,i2);
              G1.Drawline(new System.Drawing.Pen (System.Drawing.Color.Black,1),x0+round(i*mx),y0-3,x0+round(i*mx),y0+3); //засечки на оси +Х
              G1.Drawline(new System.Drawing.Pen (System.Drawing.Color.Black,1),x0-round(i*mx),y0-3,x0-round(i*mx),y0+3); //засечки на оси -Х
              G1.Drawline(new System.Drawing.Pen (System.Drawing.Color.Black,1),x0-3,y0+round(i*my),x0+3,y0+round(i*my)); //засечки на оси +Y
              G1.Drawline(new System.Drawing.Pen (System.Drawing.Color.Black,1),x0-3,y0-round(i*my),x0+3,y0-round(i*my)); //засечки на оси -Y
              G1.DrawString(i1,new System.Drawing.Font ( ' Times New Roman ' , 7 , System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold ),System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,x0+round(i*mx)-4,y0+10);//подпись оси +Х
              G1.DrawString(i2,new System.Drawing.Font ( ' Times New Roman ' , 7 , System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold ),System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,x0-round(i*mx)-6,y0+10);//подпись оси -Х
              G1.DrawString(i1,new System.Drawing.Font ( ' Times New Roman ' , 7 , System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold ),System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,x0-20,y0-round(i*my)-6);//подпись оси Y
              G1.DrawString(i2,new System.Drawing.Font ( ' Times New Roman ' , 7 , System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold ),System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,x0-25,y0+round(i*my)-6);//подпись оси -y

           end;
           G1.DrawString('X',new System.Drawing.Font ( ' Times New Roman ' , 7 , System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold ),System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,xx-30,y0-15);
           G1.DrawString('Y',new System.Drawing.Font ( ' Times New Roman ' , 7 , System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold ),System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,x0+5,10);

end;

procedure Graf(sender: Object; e: PaintEventArgs);
begin
  var g := e.Graphics;
      x:=-b;
   while x<=b do 
   begin
    if (F1(x) > -2*b) and (F1(x)< 2*b) then 
      begin
      g.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.Red, x0+round(x*mx), y0-round(F1(x)*my), 1, 1); // График
      x:=x+0.001;
      end
    else x:=x+0.001;
   end;
end;


procedure kp(Sender : Object; Args : KeyEventArgs); 
begin
  if Args.KeyCode = Keys.Enter then // это сработает при нажатии Энтер
  begin
    o := (Sender as TextBox).Text;
    Args.SuppressKeyPress := true;
    Val(o, b, code);
    writeln(b);
    Application.Run(Form1);{!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!}
  end;
end;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
begin

   //Различные параметры 
     xx:=500;
     yy:=500;
     b:=13;
     x0:=240;
     y0:=250;
     mx:=(xx-x0-30)/b;
     my:=(y0-30)/b;
     x:=-b;

  //Свойства формы 1
     Form1 := new Form();
     Form1.Text := 'Курсовая работа'; //Заголовк
     Form1.Width := 200 + xx; //Размер
     Form1.Height := yy;
     Form1.StartPosition := FormStartPosition.CenterScreen; // Центр
     Form1.BackColor := System.Drawing.Color.White; //Фон цвета
     Form1.MaximizeBox := true; // Кнопка Развернуть
     Form1.Paint+=osi; // Выполнение осей
     Form1.Paint+=Graf; // Выполнение фигур

  Txt := new TextBox;
  Txt.Left := xx+50;
  Txt.Top := 80;
  Txt.KeyDown += kp;

  Form1.Controls.Add(Txt);
  Form1.ActiveControl := Txt; //фокус на TextBox



     //Свойства рисования
     G1 := System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd (Form1.Handle);; 

     Application.Run(Form1);
end.
```

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Помнится в Delphi у формы был метод Repait. А у textBox событие onChange. Для него надо описать обработчик.

Comment: Все уже было написано. Только вызвать `Form1.Refresh`.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо запуска формы нужно очистить окно и нарисовать новый график:

```
   Program BetterKursach;
  
  {$reference System.Windows.Forms.dll}
  {$reference System.Drawing.dll}
  {$apptype windows}
  {$Val.PAS}
  uses System.Windows.Forms;
  uses System.Drawing;
  uses System;
  uses System.Net;
  
  Label m;
  
  function cot(x:real):real;
    begin
    cot:=cos(x)/sin(x);
    end;
  
  function F1(x:real):real;
    begin
    F1 := tan(x);
    end;
  
  var   
  
        Txt: TextBox;
        Form1: System.Windows.Forms.Form; 
        G1: System.Drawing.Graphics;
        i, b, x0, y0, xx, yy, code:integer;
        x, mx, my:real;
        i1, i2, o:string;
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  
  procedure osi (sender : object; e : System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs); //Построение осей
  begin
            G1.Clear(Color.White);
           G1.DrawLine (new System.Drawing.Pen (System.Drawing.Color.Black,1), 0,y0,500,y0); //Ось икс
           G1.DrawLine (new System.Drawing.Pen (System.Drawing.Color.Black,1), x0,0,x0,500); //Ось игрек
  
           for var i:=1 to b do
             begin
                str(i,i1);
                str(-i,i2);
                G1.Drawline(new System.Drawing.Pen (System.Drawing.Color.Black,1),x0+round(i*mx),y0-3,x0+round(i*mx),y0+3); //засечки на оси +Х
                G1.Drawline(new System.Drawing.Pen (System.Drawing.Color.Black,1),x0-round(i*mx),y0-3,x0-round(i*mx),y0+3); //засечки на оси -Х
                G1.Drawline(new System.Drawing.Pen (System.Drawing.Color.Black,1),x0-3,y0+round(i*my),x0+3,y0+round(i*my)); //засечки на оси +Y
                G1.Drawline(new System.Drawing.Pen (System.Drawing.Color.Black,1),x0-3,y0-round(i*my),x0+3,y0-round(i*my)); //засечки на оси -Y
                G1.DrawString(i1,new System.Drawing.Font ( ' Times New Roman ' , 7 , System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold ),System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,x0+round(i*mx)-4,y0+10);//подпись оси +Х
                G1.DrawString(i2,new System.Drawing.Font ( ' Times New Roman ' , 7 , System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold ),System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,x0-round(i*mx)-6,y0+10);//подпись оси -Х
                G1.DrawString(i1,new System.Drawing.Font ( ' Times New Roman ' , 7 , System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold ),System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,x0-20,y0-round(i*my)-6);//подпись оси Y
                G1.DrawString(i2,new System.Drawing.Font ( ' Times New Roman ' , 7 , System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold ),System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,x0-25,y0+round(i*my)-6);//подпись оси -y
  
             end;
             G1.DrawString('X',new System.Drawing.Font ( ' Times New Roman ' , 7 , System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold ),System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,xx-30,y0-15);
             G1.DrawString('Y',new System.Drawing.Font ( ' Times New Roman ' , 7 , System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold ),System.Drawing.Brushes.Black,x0+5,10);
  
  end;
  
  procedure Graf(sender: Object; e: PaintEventArgs);
  begin
    var g := e.Graphics;
        x:=-b;
     while x<=b do 
     begin
      if (F1(x) > -2*b) and (F1(x)< 2*b) then 
        begin
        g.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.Red, x0+round(x*mx), y0-round(F1(x)*my), 1, 1); // График
        x:=x+0.001;
        end
      else x:=x+0.001;
     end;
  end;
  
  
  procedure kp(Sender : Object; Args : KeyEventArgs); 
  begin
    if Args.KeyCode = Keys.Enter then // это сработает при нажатии Энтер
    begin
      o := (Sender as TextBox).Text;
      Args.SuppressKeyPress := true;
      Val(o, b, code);
      writeln(b);
      osi(new object,new PaintEventArgs(G1,new Rectangle(0,0,0,0)));
      Graf(new object,new PaintEventArgs(G1,new Rectangle(0,0,0,0)));
      //Application.Run(Form1);{!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!}
    end;
  end;
  
  /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  begin
    
     //Различные параметры 
       xx:=500;
       yy:=500;
       b:=13;
       x0:=240;
       y0:=250;
       mx:=(xx-x0-30)/b;
       my:=(y0-30)/b;
       x:=-b;
  
    //Свойства формы 1
       Form1 := new Form();
       Form1.Text := 'Курсовая работа'; //Заголовк
       Form1.Width := 200 + xx; //Размер
       Form1.Height := yy;
       Form1.StartPosition := FormStartPosition.CenterScreen; // Центр
       Form1.BackColor := System.Drawing.Color.White; //Фон цвета
       Form1.MaximizeBox := true; // Кнопка Развернуть
       Form1.Paint+=osi; // Выполнение осей
       Form1.Paint+=Graf; // Выполнение фигур
  
    Txt := new TextBox;
    Txt.Left := xx+50;
    Txt.Top := 80;
    Txt.KeyDown += kp;
    Form1.Controls.Add(Txt);
    Form1.ActiveControl := Txt; //фокус на TextBox
  
  
  
       //Свойства рисования
       G1 := System.Drawing.Graphics.FromHwnd (Form1.Handle);; 
  
       Application.Run(Form1);
```